# Submit button not showing up in the same area on different screens

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, view

My submit button shows up in very different places when i'm viewing it on different screens. I understand the usage of media queries helps with this, but I just want the items to show up in generally the same area.

I've tried using percentages for my dimensions, but the problems persists. Any recommendation? I've had luck with percentages in the past, I'm not sure why they aren't working for me with this specific problem. Is there something else wrong?

Here is my code (the styling for the submit button is at the bottom of the styling sheet):

```css
html {
    font-family: 'PT Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    background: #f1f2f6;
}

body {
    background: #f1f2f6;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.Class-Name-Bar {
    position: relative;
    height: 270px;
    width: 75%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 35px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.Class-Name {
    position: absolute;
    height: 220px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(10, 10, 25, .85), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85)), url(https://miro.medium.com/max/2656/1*d0Qd8OUx_TUxG7N6H991ew.jpeg);
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

    .Class-Name h1 {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 60px;
        margin-top: 50px;
        font-weight: 200;
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    .Class-Name p {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #f1f2f6;
        margin: -20px;
    }

#navigation {
    position: absolute;
}

div#navigation ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 86%;
    margin-left: 25px;
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 20px;
    list-style: none;
}

    div#navigation ul li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #000000;
    }

        div#navigation ul li a:hover {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #ff4757;
        }

.post-area-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 35%;
    margin-left: 52.5%;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.post-area {
    position: relative;
    width: 95%;
    margin: 2%;

}

input[type=post] {
    padding: 3%;
    width: 95%;
    border: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    background-color: #f1f2f6;
    margin-top: 3%;
}

.submit {
    position: absolute;
    border: none;
    margin-left: 83%;
    padding: 5px 16px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link href="~/css/ClassReview.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  

    <div class="Class-Name-Bar">
        <div class="Class-Name">
            <h1> Calculus</h1>
            <p> MA2500</p>
        </div>
        <div id="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Notes</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tests</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Quizlets</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="description">
    </div>

    <div class="post-area-wrapper">
        <form>
            <div class="post-area">
                <input type="post" name="post" placeholder="Review this class, tell us how you really feel..">
            </div>
            <button type=submit class="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where do you want it to be? In the "Review this class..." box? If so, where in that box do you want it? To the left, right, center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your submit button to be at the same place all the time you have to either define the exact position for it using top left right bottom or using the below code without defining the position absolute you can simply define it as a block and then give it margin-left:auto which will position it on the right side of the div and give it a small margin from the right side.

```
.submit {
    display:block;
    border: none;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-left:auto;
    padding: 5px 16px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
}
```

Comment: Welcome glad that it helped you :)